# $\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-x}}}{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x}}}$

Tags: calculus

Find the value of $\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-x}}}{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x}}}$, if $x\in \left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$. I know it is equal to $\sqrt{2}+1$, but I don't know how to prove it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the value'? It depends on $x$!

Comment: @DennisGulko: It could actually be constant..

Comment: What you wrote is the value at $x=0$, which is obtained by plugging in $0$ instead of $x$ every time.

Comment: But, how to prove it if the value would be constant?

Comment: Is it $\sqrt{2}x+1$ ?

Comment: No, it seems to be a constant, and the value of it is independent of $x \in \left(0, \frac{1}{2}\right)$. The value could be equal to $\sqrt{2}+1$.

Comment: There has got to be some sort of symmetry argument with $u=\frac{1}{2}-x$.  Then maybe chain rule or something can get a cancellation.

Comment: @CSG What book is this question from?

Answer (score 6):

$x$ can be set to $\sin^22\theta$ as $0<x<\frac 12\implies 0<\sin2\theta<\frac1{\sqrt 2}$

$\implies 0< 2\theta< \frac\pi4$

$1+\sqrt x=1+\sin2\theta=(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)^2\implies \sqrt{1+\sqrt x}=\cos\theta+\sin\theta$

$1-\sqrt x=1-\sin2\theta=(\cos\theta-\sin\theta)^2\implies \sqrt{1+\sqrt x}=\cos\theta-\sin\theta$ as $\cos\theta>\sin\theta>0$ as $0< \theta< \frac\pi8$

$1-x=\cos^2\theta, \sqrt{1-x}=\cos2\theta,$

As $\cos2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1=1-2\sin^2\theta$

$1+\sqrt{1-x}=1+\cos2\theta=2\cos^2\theta, 1-\sqrt{1-x}=1-\cos2\theta=2\sin^2\theta$

$$\text{ Then, }\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt x}+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-x}}}{\sqrt{1-\sqrt x}+\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x}}}$$

$$=\frac{\cos\theta+\sin\theta+\sqrt2\cos\theta }{\cos\theta-\sin\theta+\sqrt2\sin\theta}$$

$$=\frac{(\sqrt2+1)\cos\theta+\sin\theta }{\cos\theta+(\sqrt2-1)\sin\theta}$$

$$=(\sqrt2+1)\cdot\frac{(\sqrt2+1)\cos\theta+\sin\theta }{(\sqrt2+1)\cos\theta+(\sqrt2+1)(\sqrt2-1)\sin\theta}$$

$$=(\sqrt2+1)$$ as $(\sqrt2+1)\cos\theta+\sin\theta\ne 0$ as $\cos\theta>\sin\theta>0$ as $0< \theta< \frac\pi8$

Comment: Many Thanks! But, I also got it.

Comment: @CSG, my pleasure. Btw, how have you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

This is the result of the Taylor series of the expression at $x=0$ given by Maple:
[image]

Comment: I also checked the above function with MS excel.

Comment: I did it but it doesn't simplify as we had expected. ;-(

Comment: Could you explain how to get it?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: I'm not quite sure what exactly you need to get, but anyway - a good place to start with those kind of expresions is to use the following
$$(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2 \Rightarrow a+b=(a+b)\frac{a-b}{a-b}=\frac{a^2-b^2}{a-b}$$
Plug $a=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}$ and $b=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-x}}$, that will simplify the numerator a little. Then you can repeat this.

Comment: I had already tried to use this method, but, I didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

a$\sqrt{1-\sqrt{x}}=a$

$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}=b$

$ab=\sqrt{1-x}$

Now your expression will look something like :

$\frac{b+\sqrt{1+ab}}{a
+\sqrt{1-ab}}$

Comment: Your last sentence is wrong!
In the denominator, it should be $a+...$. I guess so...

Comment: Yeah! Thanks. Thats why I couldn't go further.:)

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=\sqrt{1-\sqrt{x}}, b=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}$, and $b>a>0$ for all $x\in\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$. One could get that $ab=\sqrt{1-x}$, $b^2-a^2=2\sqrt{x}$, $1-a^2b^2=\sqrt{x}$, and $b^2+a^2=2$. Then, one could obtain: $b+a=\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{1+ab}$ and $b-a=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-ab}$.
Now, when one would prove that the value of the above function is equal to $\sqrt{2}+1$ for all $x\in\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$. Given $y=f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-x}}}{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x}}}=\frac{b+\sqrt{1+ab}}{a+\sqrt{1-ab}}\equiv \sqrt{2}+1$. So, it only required to prove that $y^2-2y-1=0$. The proof is the same as to prove that $\left(\frac{b+\sqrt{1+ab}}{a+\sqrt{1-ab}}\right)^2-2\left(\frac{b+\sqrt{1+ab}}{a+\sqrt{1-ab}}\right)-\left(\frac{a+\sqrt{1-ab}}{a+\sqrt{1-ab}}\right)$ shall be equal to zero for all $x\in\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$. In the case of a non-trivial solution being existed in, the portion of denominator shall not be equal to zero, and the numerator shall be zero. After expansion, one got the portion of numerator as follows: $(b+\sqrt{1+ab})^2-2(b+\sqrt{1+ab})(a+\sqrt{1-ab})-(a+\sqrt{1-ab})^2=b^2-a^2+2ab-2ab+2(b-a)\sqrt{1+ab}-2(b+a)\sqrt{1-ab}-2\sqrt{1-a^2b^2}\equiv 2\sqrt{x}+2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-ab}\sqrt{1+ab}-2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+ab}\sqrt{1-ab}-2\sqrt{1-a^2b^2}=2\sqrt{x}+2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-a^2b^2}-2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-a^2b^2}-2\sqrt{x}=0$. So, the proof was done, and we show that $y=f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1-x}}}{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x}}}\equiv\sqrt{2}+1$, $\forall x\in\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$.

Comment: If indeed $ab=\sqrt{1-x}$ then $1-a^2b^2=1-(ab)^2=1-(1-x)=x$ and not $\sqrt{x}$ as claimed.